# How to include header file only if framework is added/linked in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm working on a Xcode project with Objective C that has optional frameworks which means that some code is executed from that particular framework only if it is linked/exists in project. The current framework that I'm using is PassKit. How can I achieve this? Is there some macro that can tell is framework linked or it is not? Something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
#if __has_include("PassKit.h") && __has_include(<PassKit.h>)
#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>
#endif

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     if ([PKPassLibrary class]) {
         UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"PassKit Test"
                                message:@"PassKit is linked."
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

      UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                   NSLog(@"Ok pressed...");
                               }];

       [alert addAction:okButton];

       [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
   }}
```

Also I have set **Link Frameworks Automatically** to **NO** in my target. Thanks for your answers and help.

Comment: Include it normally, but check if the function is available before using. Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038137/xcode-and-optional-frameworks

Comment: I still don't get it how I can use this... Is `weak_import` in this `function extern int MyWeakLinkedFunction() __attribute__((weak_import));` parameter for framework name? How can I connect this with PassKit?

Comment: I need something that will tell me if framework exists during run time. If framework exists, it will run code.

Comment: I found a solution. I've implemented this method: 
`- (BOOL)checkIfFrameworkIsLinked:(NSString *)className {
    BOOL isFrameworkLinked = (NSClassFromString(className) != nil);
    return isFrameworkLinked;
}`
and it works fine.

Comment: Hello, can I do that with frameworks written in swift? we have been struggling for a week.. here is our problem, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077857/if-canimport-does-not-find-frameworks-with-cocoapods

Answer (score 3):

```
#if __has_include(<PassKit/PassKit.h>) || __has_include("PassKit.h")
#define XXXPKTrigger
#endif

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
#ifdef XXXPKTrigger
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"PassKit Test"
                                message:@"PassKit is linked."
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                   NSLog(@"Ok pressed...");
                               }];

    [alert addAction:okButton];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
#else
// do another logic
#endif
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Hello, can I do that with frameworks written in swift? we have been struggling for a week.. here is our problem, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077857/if-canimport-does-not-find-frameworks-with-cocoapods