# How to weak link a pod to another pod?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have the following

- A 3rd party xcframework (`ThirdPartyFramework`)
- A private pod (written in Swift) that wraps the above xcframework (`AdditionalSDK`)
- The main SDK pod, also written in Swift (`MainSDK`)
- A project (`MyProject`)

What I want to achieve is `MainSDK` to use functionality from `AdditionalSDK`, if `AdditionalSDK` is present. If not, `MainSDK` should continue to work without the `AdditionalSDK`'s functionality.

After digging around I stumbled into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077857/if-canimport-does-not-find-frameworks-with-cocoapods/55560102), which led me to this [guide](https://medium.com/5-minute-break-while-coding/create-a-mostly-swift-framework-with-optional-features-7e8a9ac960f9). I've tried other guides as well, without any luck. I've also noticed that in the original question, each podspec defines a vendored framework (Firebase, Facebook and other major SDKs also do the same).  In my case **only** the `AdditionalSDK` defines a vendored framework. The `MainSDK` defines its source files (along with headers, modulemap, etc).

The `#if canImport(AdditionalSDK)` didn't work for me, as the guide also states. I then tried to implement Obj-C interoperability classes. I.e. I added `AdditionalSDKInterop.{h,m}` as below

```
// AdditionalSDKInterop.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MainSDK/MainSDK-Swift.h> // <-- First problem here

@interface AdditionalSDKInterop : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MainSDKInteropDelegate> delegate;

+ (BOOL)isModuleAvailable;

@end
```

```
// AdditionalSDKInterop.m

#import "AdditionalSDKInterop.h"
@import AdditionalSDK; // <-- Second problem here

@implementation AdditionalSDKInterop

+ (BOOL)isModuleAvailable {
    if ([AdditionalSDK class]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

The `MainSDKInteropDelegate` is a protocol in the `MainSDK`, which defines the methods that can be called from the `AdditionalSDK`.

```
@objc public protocol MainSDKInteropDelegate: class {
    @objc func initializeSDK()
}
```

My first problem is that I get `MainSDK/MainSDK-Swift.h file not found` in the `AdditionalSDKInterop.h`, but strangely not always. Bear in mind that I clean my project and I delete the Derived data prior to each build. Still, sometimes I get this error, sometimes not. My second problem is that I get `Module AdditionalSDK not found`, if I don't add `pod 'AdditionalSDK'` in the project's podfile.

What am I missing, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is like this:

1. Anything used from `AdditionalSDK` in your other classes should be used via protocols.
2. Have 2 implementations for those protocols: one with `AdditionalSDK`, and one as no-op (does nothing). It can be even a default extension on your protocols.
3. Have a factory class that takes classes you implemented in Step 2, based on some "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags".
4. Create 2 build targets: one for case with `AdditionalSDK`, and one for case without `AdditionalSDK`. The first target will include `AdditionalSDK` Pod, and classes you created in step 2 that use it. And it will set the flag to value that matches "has `AdditionalSDK`". The other target will include no-op classes, and opposite of the flag. Th e factory class itself you created in step 3 won't include anything from `AdditionalSDK`, so it can be included in both targets.

Roughly something like this:

```
// Member of both targets. Your classes only use this protocol
protocol MyOptionalSDKProxy {
   func something()
   ...
}

// Member of both targets
extension MyOptionalSDKProxy {
   func something() { /* no-op*/ }
}

// Member of target with AdditionalSDK
import AdditionalSDK //<-- only here import Additional SDK
class MyProxyWithAdditionalSDK: MyOptionalSDKProxy {
   func something() { print("hello from AdditionalSDK") }
}

// Member of target with no AdditionalSDK
class MyNoOpProxy: MyOptionalSDKProxy {}

// Member of both targets
class MyProxyFactory {
    static var proxy: MyOptionalSDKProxy {
        #if USEADDITIONALSDK // <-- a flag defined for target with AdditionalSDK
           return MyProxyWithAdditionalSDK()
        #else
           return MyNoOpProxy()
        #endif
    }
}

// Usage
let myProxy = MyProxyFactory.proxy
proxy.something()
```

Comment: Hey @Kiril S, firstly thanks for the effort. From my understanding this assumes that I have access to set flags on the project's targets, which is not the case. `MyProject` is a developer's project who wants to integrate my `MainSDK`, maybe the `AdditionalSDK` as well.

Am I right or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: what I was suggesting is that `MyProject` sets that flag. So basically I suggest that your "maybe wants to integrate with AdditionalSDK" is expressed as 2 targets, with a different compile-time flag on `MyProject`