# Conditionally import a cocoapod framework (own framework) present in app inside another cocoapod framework (own framework)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sdk, frameworks

I have two custom frameworks (Main and Child )both present on cocoapods. I want to conditionally import my child.framework into my Main.framework If user has installed child.framework. I am unable to conditionally import child framework into my main.framework as canImport always fails even If user has installed child.framework

I expected that in my main framework `#if canImport(childFramework)` will succeed If user has installed child.framework but It's always getting failed.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077857/if-canimport-does-not-find-frameworks-with-cocoapods

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.