# How to handle optinal dependency in swift dynamic framework while XCFramework generating

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ios-frameworks, xcframework

I has a SDK named **ProductSDK**. This SDK also have two dependency sdks.

1. CommonDependencySDK
2. AdvanceDependencySDK

And try to generate XCFramework in **ProductSDK**. My use case is, 2 types of use case in this **ProductSDK**. One is **ProductSDK with CommonDependencySDK** and another one is **ProductSDK with CommonDependencySDK and AdvanceDependencySDK**. Handle this case using some macros in my **ProductSDK**.

But now i need two version of XCFramework for my **ProductSDK**. One version is compiled **ProductSDK** source with **CommonDependencySDK** and another one is **ProductSDK** source with **CommonDependencySDK and AdvanceDependencySDK**.

Anyone have any ideas to this use case?

Or what is a alternative way of handling optional dependency instead of macros.

```
#if canImport(SDKName)
    // Some codes
#else
    // Some codes
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XCFrameworks` are supposed to replace universal frameworks by incorporating binaries of the **target library** for different platforms. Nothing changed in regards to including **dependencies** under the frameworks, however. Such approach is commonly called "umbrella" frameworks and are [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged).

What you are supposed to do instead is to instruct your end-users to link their projects against dependencies your framework relies on, and suggesting that only one dependency is required, while the other just expands the functionality.

For the part how to implement optionally linked frameworks, it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834717/what-are-the-libraries-linking-options-in-xcode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038137/xcode-and-optional-frameworks).